# Yii required asterisk not showing on first load?

Tags: php, yii

I have an issue where the required asterisk is not showing even though a field is required.

Strange that when you submit and there are errors on the form the label now renders with an asterisk.

In the view:

```
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'password', array('class' => 'control-label col-sm-4','label'=>'Enter a New Password')); ?>
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'repeat_password', array('class' => 'control-label col-sm-4','label'=>'Repeat the New Password'))); ?>
```

The password one works.

Model:

```
array('email, password', 'required', 'except' => 'reset'),
array('password', 'required', 'on' => 'reset'),
array('email, password', 'length', 'max'=>255),
array('password', 'length', 'min' => 1),
array('repeat_password', 'required', 'on' => 'register, reset'),
array('repeat_password', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'password', 'on' => 'register, reset'),
array('password', 'encrypt', 'on' => 'register, reset'),
```

[image: On Load]

[image: After failed]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to:

```
array('password, repeat_password', 'required', 'on' => 'register, reset'),
array('repeat_password', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'password', 'on' =>'register, reset'),
array('password', 'length', 'min' => 1),
array('password', 'encrypt', 'on' => 'register, reset')
```

I think it was overwriting the first rule. Not sure though.

Comment: It didn't work. It doesn't show on first load but then they show when a failed submit is sent. I have updated the question as I noticed an extra rule. Remember this is the `reset` action

Comment: @surfer190 Since the validation works fine(?) and you are satisfied with backend solution you could try this hacky way <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'repeat_password', array('class' => 'control-label col-sm-4', 'required' => true)); ?> I hate suggesting these kind of stuff but for you it might actually work